# RxJS extract data from stream on external condition

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Context: I have a logging library for an app and I want to use Rx Subject to write logs to database.
Problem: Logs are generated before the connection to database is established and the connection can become unavailable at any time, but I have and observable that either contains an object with methods for working with the database or an undefined. What I want to do is to keep the logs in the stream while database persistence is undefined and resume when it's available.

I think the code should look something like this:

```
logsSubject
           .takeWhen(/* test for database persistence */) // made up name because I don't know a Rx method that does what I want
           .subscribe(/* write data to database */);
```

I'm not sure however if this is actually possible for I've been using RxJS for a very short time

Answer (score 1):

Following code is to simulate your scenario. The db will connect every 10s and disconnect every 5s after it connected. In real use case connect and disconnect should be both shared Observable or Subject. Instead of takeUntil operator I used a merge here because takeUntil will just completed the observable sequence and you won't be able to resume it. (repeatWhen operator should work but it seems missing in Rxjs 5)

```
//emit value every 1s
const logWrite = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)

const dbConnected = new Rx.Subject()
// make it fire every 10s 
Rx.Observable.interval(10000).do(()=>dbConnected.next('db 
connected')).subscribe()

const dbDisconnected = Rx.Observable.timer(3000)
.flatMap(()=>Rx.Observable.throw('db disconnected'))


const writeWhenConnected = logWrite.merge(dbDisconnected)
.retryWhen(function(errors) {
    return errors.switchMap(()=>dbConnected);
});

writeWhenConnected.subscribe(val => console.log(val),console.warn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way around:

```
Observable.combineLatest(dbConnection, logsSubject, (db, logs) => {
    // whatever: db.save(...)
  })
  .do(/* or since it's a side effect it should probably go here instead */)
```

This way [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest) will wait until both source Observable emit and will hold the `dbConnection` even though it emitted just one item.

Comment: This is great for the first time, but `dbConnection` emits multiple times, since the connection can be reseted after the boot and I would like to extract data from logsSubject only if `!!db === true`.

Comment: Then you can chain it with `dbConnection.filter(db => !!db)` before putting in into `combineLatest`

Answer (score 0):

What it seems that I needed was pausableBuffered from RxJS4 but since it's been removed in RxJS5 I ended up with the following solution:

```
let dbAvailability = dbSubject
         .switchMap((db) => db ? logSubject : Rx.Observable.never());

//get data only when dbAvailability emits, and that happens only when I have a connection
let bufferedLogs = logSubject.buffer(dbAvailability);

bufferedLogs
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe(/* save to database */);
```